# Ember 2.1.0 render partial if index page else another partial

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

In my templates/application.hbs I would like to be able to set a condition to check if it is my index page I render a navigation for it, else it would render another set of navigation for in-app pages. The same for my footer. What is the best way to check this? Also, whether a user is login or not doesn't matter.

My research has lead to outdated code or convention. I'm also completely new to Ember so any help would be very much appreciated.

Here is my emblem attempt, but not working:

`if eq currentRouteName="index"
   = partial 'partialName'
 else
   = partial 'partialName2'`

Second attempt works:

First run: ember install ember-truth-helpers

Add this to my application template:

`if (eq currentRouteName "index")
   = partial 'partialName'
 else
   = partial 'partialName2'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The application controller has a property `currentRouteName`. You can choose which navigation to render based on its value.

In your `application.hbs`

```
{{#if (eq currentRouteName "index")}}
  render navigation for your index page
{{else}}
  render navigation for other pages
{{/if}}
```

The `eq` helper comes from [ember-truth-helpers](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ember-truth-helpers)

Comment: Got the right syntax in for emblem like my example on my original post above and everything works great. Thank you!

Comment: Side question, how can I check for two different route using ember-truth-helper? For example, I wanted to check if it's not either one of the two routes display my navigation. The code below is the best format I can come up with without much guideline:
`if (not-eq (eq currentRouteName "index" ) (eq currentRouteName "signup") )`

Comment: Pretty close. You probably want `and` or `or` instead of the `not-eq/xor`. e.g. `if (and (eq currentRouteName "index" ) (eq currentRouteName "signup") )`. If the logic gets complex enough you should make a property on your controller/component.

Comment: It doesn't like having two sets like that, my build would break. Anything else that I might be missing? Or how do I write that in controller or component?

Comment: You can put a computed property in your application controller. `shouldRenderNavigation: Ember.computed('currentRouteName', function() { let route = this.get('currentRouteName'); return route === 'index' || route === 'signup' })`